# Devise authentication - devise_error_messages! in a view causes "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, devise, registration

devise_error_messages! in a view causes

```
undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass
```

after `render :new` in `create` method. This started happening after I inherited RegistrationsController from "Devise::RegistrationsController" instead of "ApplicationController". Initial rendering of "new" method does not cause any exceptions.

Overridden registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    begin
      raise I18n.t("registration_disabled") unless registration_enabled?
      ....................
    rescue => ex
      flash[:alert] = ex.message
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

The view registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<h2><%= I18n.t("sign_up_title") %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div><%= f.label :login, I18n.t("the_login") %> <span class="mandatory">*</span><br />
      <%= f.text_field :login %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password, I18n.t("password") %> <span class="mandatory">*</span><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation, I18n.t("password_confirmation") %> <span class="mandatory">*</span><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

    <div><%= f.submit from_admin? ? I18n.t("sign_up_other") : I18n.t("sign_up") %></div>
    <p class="mandatory">* - <%= I18n.t("mandatory_fields") %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/links" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because you're raising the exception before the object (devise calls it the resource) is created.
And it is needed by the [devise_error_messages](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb) helper.

If you want to prevent access to the registration, there are other ways to achieve this:

One way could be :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    if registration_enabled?
      super
    else
      flash[:alert] = I18n.t("registration_disabled")
      redirect_to action: :new
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not 100% sure if this would work but this idea is to render the view with the flash if user can't register, so this would behave as the "initial rendering"

EDIT : Actually I believe that changing your

```
render action: :new
```

to

```
redirect_to action: :new
```

would be enough to prevent the error as the redirect_to will execute the methode whereas the render just render the associate view.

Comment: The idea is that registration_enabled? is not the only reason which may cause exception. It could be raised out of some "natural" reasons, for example, error while doing user.save! or something else, and all these situations should be handled the proper way, namely - by displaying an error message on the live page instead of crashing.

Comment: By the way, inserting a "soft" conditional exit instead of raising exception didn't change anything. It crashes as soon as it executes "render :new". "redirect_to :action => :new" does the job.

Comment: Yes I realized afterward that the "soft" conditional was actually useless.