# Rspec for Devise: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_password, user_password_confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, mass-assignment

I am trying to write a **sign up spec** for [Devise 2.2.2](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) using RSpec. I prepared the `User` model as usual.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  rolify

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable

  after_create :add_default_role

  def add_default_role
    add_role :user
  end
end
```

In the spec I need to sign up the `user` using the `password` and `password_confirmation` as show below.

```
# spec/requests/users/sign_up_spec.rb
describe 'Sign up' do

  before(:each) do
    sign_out
  end

  it 'signs up a visitor with valid data' do
    user  = build(:user)

    click_link I18n.t('layouts.navigation.sign_up')
    fill_in I18n.t('devise.registrations.new.name'), with: user.name
    fill_in I18n.t('devise.registrations.new.email'), with: user.email

    find('.js-password').set user.password
    find('.js-password-confirmation').set user.password_confirmation

    click_button I18n.t('devise.registrations.new.submit')

    expect(page).to have_content I18n.t('layouts.navigation.sign_out')
    expect(page).not_to have_content I18n.t('layouts.navigation.sign_up')
    expect(page).not_to have_content I18n.t('layouts.navigation.sign_in')
  end
end
```

Here is the Devise view template that is used to render the page:

```
<!-- app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb -->
<h2><%= t('.title', :default => "Sign up") %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :name, t('.name', :default => "Name" ) %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email, t('.email', :default => "Email" ) %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :user_password, t('.user_password', :default => "Password" ) %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :user_password, class: 'js-password' %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :user_password_confirmation, t('.user_password_confirmation', :default => "Password confirmation" ) %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :user_password_confirmation, class: 'js-password-confirmation' %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit t('.submit', :default => "Submit") %></div>
<% end %>
```

Although I added both attributes to `attr_accessible` this error message is thrown at me:

```
Sign up signs up a visitor with valid data
  Failure/Error: click_button I18n.t('devise.registrations.new.submit')
  ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
    Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_password, user_password_confirmation
   # ./spec/requests/users/sign_up_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: I'm not sure but if something never works properly for me I always restart spork, or do a rake db:test:prepare

Comment: It produces the same error running pure `rspec spec/requests/users/sign_up_spec.rb`. I also migrated up from zero and prepared the test database.

Comment: I've never used Devise, but, maybe it's something in the devise files rather than your own model? I'm not sure just guessing

Comment: The name of the inputs in your form are wrong, should be something like `user[password]` & `user[password_confirmation]`, yet the error is saying that you have `user_password` & `user_password_confirmation`

Comment: @pjam I guess your advise leaded me into the right direction. Please extract your post as an answer so I can grant you the flag. As seen in [similar post here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12665527/356895) I have to use `password` instead of `user_password` in the view template.

Comment: Well, that's nice of you, I'm doing it right now :)

Comment: Cool. Let's delete the previous post to keep the noise level low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the inputs in your form are wrong, should be something like `user[password]` & `user[password_confirmation]`, yet the error is saying that you have `user_password` & `user_password_confirmation`

---

The relevant changes in the view template can be seen here:

```
<div><%= f.label :password, t('.password', :default => "Password" ) %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, class: 'js-password' %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password_confirmation, t('.password_confirmation', :default => "Password confirmation" ) %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'js-password-confirmation' %></div>
```